# Is it possible to delete a file through the Google Drive app?

Tags: applications, google-apps, google-drive

In the Google Drive app, on its home screen, I get a list of files and a "3 dots" menu next to each file. When I open the menu, all of the options given to me are:

- Share
- Add to Starred
- Make available offline
- Link sharing off
- Copy link
- Make a copy
- Send a copy
- Open with
- Download
- Rename
- Show file location
- Details & activity
- Print
- Add to Home screen
- Report abuse

While these are a ton of options, none of them are "Delete" or "Remove" or similar. I tried looking in the "Details & activity" section to see if there was a "Delete" option, but there was not. Is there a way to delete files through the Google Drive app, or do I have to use the website to delete files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, but not on Google Drive's home screen.**

The [Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375102?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) mentions the following:

> #### Put a file in trash
>
> To remove a file from your Drive, you can put it in your trash. Your file will stay there until you empty your trash.
>
> If you're the owner of the file, others can view it until you permanently delete the file. If you're not the owner, others can see the file even if you empty your trash.
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Google Drive app.
> 2. At the bottom right, tap Files [image: Files].
> 3. Next to the file you want to delete, tap More [image: More] [image: and then] **Remove**.

Alternatively, you can also long-press and select multiple files, then tap "Remove" (trash icon) on the toolbar.

Note that you can also do this on "Starred" and "Shared", but not on "Home".

---

To actually remove the files, you also need to empty the trash.

> #### Empty your trash
>
> You can permanently delete an individual file or empty your entire trash. After deleting a file, anyone you've shared the file with will lose access to it. If you want others to be able to still view the file, you can give ownership to someone else.
>
> 1. In the upper left, tap Menu [image: Menu] [image: and then] Trash.
> 2. Next to the file you'd like to delete, tap More [image: More] [image: and then] **Delete forever**.